# Quick Getting Started Issue

Tags: mamp

I’ve been carefully following the instructions laid out at http://una.im/2013/08/13/the-absolute-beginners-guide-to-setting-up-craft-on-mac.html# and http://a73cram5ay.blogspot.com/2015/04/installing-craft-cms-on-mac-os-x-using.html to get Craft up and running. I’ve meticulously followed the steps on both, but am stuck in the same place either way. I’m a total noob, so hoping it isn’t something stupid I’ve overlooked.

Step 5 in the Almost Profound guide and P5 in the a73cram5ay guide are not working for me. I have the MAMP site started and the tab is open in my browser (Chrome). I’ve tried both the socket and standard connections (images of my settings attached). Still, neither will connect.

I get the message:

Connection Failed!

Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1, or the request timed out.

Be sure that the address is correct and that you have the necessary privileges, or try increasing the connection timeout (currently 10 seconds).

MySQL said: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (61)

---

I am the administrator and have privileges…

What am I doing wrong? I really want to try out Craft : (

Thanks for your time,

Shawn

[image: Socket]
[image: Standard]

Comment: Hi Shawn, welcome to Craft (and Stack Exchange)! To be honest, this is barely a Craft question... You're having database connection issues, which are not specifically related to Craft. We may end up migrating this post to Stack Overflow, where it can be seen by a much broader audience.

Comment: Are you sure MySQL is running?  Do you see the green dot next to "MySQL Server"?

Comment: https://imgur.com/AxRMmil

Comment: What do you see from MAMP when you click the "Open WebStart page"? Does it show you any database connection information there?

Comment: I tried to recreate what I think your situation is. Here's how I can connect to my database with MAMP (Standard, not Pro) and Sequel Pro:

Comment: https://www.evernote.com/l/AAHrjPbIsWdLLoK18UlZkSv0GrVnX3KkwW4

Comment: Oh my god...I just accidentally pasted the link"/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock" twice and couldn't tell because the window was too small.